# Mocha: get stacktrace when running mocha programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am running tests using mocha programmatically and able to run the tests, get full title using following code but I couldn't find any way to get complete stack trace that is being printed on the commandline. How do I get the complete stack trace using mocha as library.

```
mocha.run(function(failures){
    if (failures) {
        console.log('it failed');
    } else {
        console.log('it passed');
    }
    process.on('exit', function () {
        process.exit(failures);
    });
}).on('fail', function(test){
    title =  test.fullTitle();
}).on('pass', function(test){
    title =  test.fullTitle();
});
```

Comment: You can use `var err = new Error(); console.log(err.stack);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to get stacktrace with

```
var stackTrace = test.err.stack;
```